# Custom list with introduction and picture

Tags: 2013

I am using SharePoint 2013 and have a requirement to create a list in which HR employee can enter a photograph of newly inducted employee and some 6 lines of introductory text. That would be added as webpart on homepage and once staff would click on newly employee name it should show the picture with introduction.

Is it possible with custom list and how? or requires visual studio webpart?

Comment: You need show only in popup window?

Comment: Do you have MySites? If yes, you could use OOTB contacts list and achieve the results without and development effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not against writing code than Visual Studio Web Part is the best solution, its quite scalable and I can't think of any disadvantages..

However you can also achieve it using the new Client Side Rendering (JSLink) option in SharePoint 2013. Using CSR you can alter the default list view, there are many examples available on the internet.

Comment: CSR seems not so elegant for some odd reasons..I think i would opt for Visual Studio Webpart and use GridView control with page navigation..this way I will have more control I guess..but I wanted something easy as I am abit lazy :)

Comment: Use Repeater control instead Grid View, you will have even more control over the HTML..

Answer (score 0):

**Start with Picture Library**

You can add images in it along with personal details of users.

**Use [My Site](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/introduction-to-my-site-HA010108748.aspx)**

You can add a Webpart in page which will display **My Site** for each user on page.